# xhgui does not show php native functions

Tags: php, profiling

I'm learning how to use Xhgui (0.4.0) tool. When i was reading tutorials about it, I saw that in profiles occurs all of called functions - even php native functions just like array_filter etc. In my Xhgui installation i've tried profile simple script:

```
<?php
  sleep(5);
```

but Xhgui prints only

- ???_op   1   5,000,359 µs    0 µs    752 bytes   0 bytes 5,000,359 µs    0 µs    752 bytes   0 bytes
- load::web/app.php   1   5,757 µs    0 µs    3,880 bytes 7,200 bytes 5,757 µs    0 µs    3,880 bytes 7,200 bytes
- main()   1   360 µs  0 µs    1,040 bytes 1,000 bytes 5,006,509 µs    0 µs    6,480 bytes 8,200 bytes
- {closure}

Is it some special option to enable list native functions ?

Answer (score 1):

Acording to there github issue tracking it's a known issue once OPCache gets involved.

This happens when op code caching gets involved. Are you using PHP 5.5 by any chance?

> You might want to use FriendsOfPHP/uprofiler instead of xhprof. The current published versions of xhprof don't work so well with PHP5.5.